# How to use DDL to change the "Required" property of a column in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In an access table I have a column which has the "Required" property set to "True". I need a query which would change it to "False". I tried the following without success:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTbl] ALTER COLUMN [MyCol] VARCHAR(30) NULL;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jet SQL, the underlying SQL engine in Access does not allow you to modify the null property on columns.  The work around for doing this is to:

1. Create a new temporary column (B) which allows nulls.
2. Copy the data from the old column (A) to the new column (B).
3. Drop the old column (A).
4. Create a new column (C) with the same name as the old column (A).  Make sure the new column (C) has the correct null constraint.
5. Copy the data back from the temporary new column (B) to the newly added column (C).
6. Drop Column B.

Comment: tschaible...pretty sure you answer is plain wrong.  See my answer below.
Seth

Comment: -1 "Jet SQL, the underlying SQL engine in Access does not allow you to modify the null property on columns" is false.

Comment: +1 I tested this again and seems I was wrong. Indeed can't be done with SQL DDL.

Answer (score 6):

Access (Jet/ACE) DDL will allow you to change a field's `Required` property from False to True. Here is an example in the Access Immediate window:

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Required
False
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [MyTbl] ALTER COLUMN [MyCol] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL;"
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Required
True
```

However, you want the opposite --- change `Required` from True to False.  Access DDL will not do that.  In this example, the requested field size is applied, but the `Required` property is unchanged.  And Access does not throw an error:

```vb
CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Required = True
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Required
True
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Size
 10 
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [MyTbl] ALTER COLUMN [MyCol] VARCHAR(30) NULL;"
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Required
True
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Size
 30
```

And if you exclude any mention of Null in the DDL statement, `Required` is still unchanged:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [MyTbl] ALTER COLUMN [MyCol] VARCHAR(30);"
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Required
True
```

For an alternative, you can use a mix of Access DDL and DML as @tschaible and @hawbsl demonstrated.  However that approach seems like too much effort to me.  I would prefer the approach @Caltor suggested.  If that is practical for you, it might even be as simple as this ...

```vb
CurrentDb.TableDefs("MyTbl").Fields("MyCol").Required = False
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are programming in Access you can use the following VBA code:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim tbl As TableDef

Set db = OpenDatabase("MyDB.mdb", True) '' Open for Exclusive access
Set tbl = db.TableDefs("MyTbl")
tbl.Fields("MyCol").Required = False

'' Cleanup
Set tbl = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the tschaibles answer given above is COMPLETELY INCORRECT.  It IS true that you cannot change the required property using the query engine.  But I am almost positive you can change it using VBA.

Your question is confusing...could you clarify a few things.

Do you want to permanently changed the required property.  If so, you can change that property in the table designer at any time.

Do you want to change the property under certain conditions at runtime?  Sort of a Change the property, Do Something, Change it back scenario.  In that case you can't use the query engine to do it but I am almost positive you can do it through VBA.  So it can be done.  Most if not all things that can be done through the UI can be done through the VBA code.

If, you want to do this at runtime but you are merely using an Access file as the data store of a .net application (using the OleDB provider of ado.net) then you do have an issue.   I would recommend you use another data provider (like vistaDB).  So can you provide some details then I might can dig a little and give you a more thorough answer.

Seth

Comment: Thanks Seth. I cannot use VBA or user interaction. The query should be part of an upgrade script which is executed automatically by an application.

Comment: I think you are out of luck completely.  I am pretty sure that using ADO.NET there is no way of doing ddl statements against an Access database.  Yuck.  If you could guarantee that access was installed you could use ole automation to fire up access and do it.  But you have no control over the target environment or know that access is not and will not be installed then I am pretty sure there is nothing you can do.

Seth

Comment: Why can't you use VBA?  I use DAO collections all the time to update/add tables, fields, indexes and relationships.

Comment: Tony,

Wouldn't access have to be installed to do that?

Seth

Comment: Seth, good point.  I'm used to posters who have Access to be asking these kinds of questions.  <smile>

Comment: No. DAO is installed on every version of Windows starting with 2000, because it's the native interface for Jet, which is a Windows component.

Comment: -1 "It IS true that you cannot change the required property using the query engine" is false ;)

Comment: David, I know dao is installed...the issue is, is vba installed.  This question was vague on the details.  If the questioner has complete control over installation of his app then no problem.  If not then this matters a great deal.

onedaywhen.  Do you have a code example or another question you have answered that shows using JET (or some other NATIVELY INSTALLED LIBRARY) to make ddl changes on an access database.  (Or I guess changing the required property?)  I am not disputing your answer, I merely would like to know how to do this?

Seth

Comment: As for Jet being installed on every version of windows.  That is true...but there is NO 64 bit version of jet so only 32 bit apps can use it.  I mention that as an interesting aside.  And microsoft has no plans to do the port to 64-bit.  Does not bode well for jets future. Seth

Comment: @Seth: I edited this answer to add links to an old article on SQL DDL for the Access database engine.

Comment: @Seth: then I tested it again just to be sure and, what do you know,  it indeed isn't possible with SQL DDL. Sorry for the time waste.

Comment: I am very surprised to learn that Jet DOES support some DDL constructs.  I never new that.  HEre is an article.  
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966376.aspx.

Comment: @SethSpearman Could you tell me how to change the "Required" setting using VBA (within Access) please?

Answer (score 1):

@Hansup's answer is correct, so using pure DDL the only solution is per @tschaible's answer.

For completeness, and to add to @tschaible's answer (and as a note to self) here's the full DDL. Substitute in your own field name and datatype.

Example assumes `Person` table with a field `BirthDate` which we now want to make optional:

```
ALTER TABLE Person ADD COLUMN BirthDate2 DATE;
UPDATE Person SET BirthDate2=BirthDate;
ALTER TABLE Person DROP COLUMN BirthDate;
ALTER TABLE Person ADD COLUMN BirthDate DATE;
UPDATE Person SET BirthDate=BirthDate2;
ALTER TABLE Person DROP COLUMN BirthDate2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try referenceing ADOX in your application (.NET ?).
[ADOX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/ado270/htm/admscadoapireference.asp) On the Table object you can set the attribute to Nullable (You'll have to look into the new conventions in .NET compared to VB 6 which handled this similar to VBA).